# Laravel Nova file upload saves as .bin file

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Uploading a [.pdc](https://filext.com/file-extension/PDC) file with Laravel Nova, it saves as a `.bin` file. How can I save it as a `.pdc` file?

[image: Laravel Nova .bin upload]

Using the latest Laravel and the latest Nova

```php
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),

        File::make('File', 'filepath')
            ->rules('required', 'file')
            ->disk('reports'),
    ];
}
```

Similar question [here](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/1186) but doesn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nova has a function called `storeAs()` where you have a callback to give it a name to save as:

```php
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),

        File::make('File', 'filepath')
            ->rules('required', 'file')
            ->disk('reports')
            ->storeAs(function(Request $request) {
                return sha1(time()) . '.' . $request->file('filepath')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            }),
    ];
}
```

This will result to: `b0954b560d9ad5c96a7502672535d3bcbfd92f3a.pdc`

---

Credits to [Screenbeetle](https://laracasts.com/@Screenbeetle) and [edoc](https://laracasts.com/@edoc)